Перестали работать подсказки импортом в PyCharm
Пересел на новый пк, установил все программы, но заметил некую проблему, связанную с подсказками импортов. Кто работает в PyCharm, знает, что там можно написать метод и нажать на красную лампочку, где выведутся список библиотек, откуда можно импортировать данный метод. Вот это как раз и пропало. Пробовал очистить кэш интерпретатора, не помогло. Менял интерпретатор на новый с виртуальный окружением, тоже не помогает. К примеру, работаю через poetry, в файле pyproject.toml есть библиотека django установленная, но через подсказки всплывающие, PyCharm не видит библиотеку. Если начать писать вручную импорт, все находит. Ниже приложу скриншоты, если кто-то поможет решить данную проблему, буду благодарен.





Импорт на лету по умолчанию отключен.
Включается в разделе Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import установкой галочки Show auto-import tooltip:


не помогло, поставил галочку, пайчарм не видит библиотеку джанго, хотя она стоит в проекте
